# Troubles "porting" cURL from bash to PHP

Tags: php, bash, curl

I'm trying to port this command to PHP:

```
curl -i -X POST http://website.com \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" \
-H "Accept: Application/json" \
-H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" --data "var1=output1&var2=output2"
```

From bash it works.. I get **[this](http://pastebin.com/Huv7u3hp)** JSON output.

This is what I wrote in PHP to try to get the same result:

```
<?php
function blabla() {

    $curl_parameters = array(
        'var1'    =>  "output1",
        'var2'    =>  "output2",
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://website.com");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query( $curl_parameters ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
        "Content-Type"      => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept"            => "Application/json",
        "X-Requested-With"  => "XMLHttpRequest",
    ));

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}

echo blabla();
?>
```

Unfortunately with this snippet I just get a 302 Found HTTP header as output ([this](http://pastebin.com/szQW7DcX)).. seems like the variables are not passed (the `--data` part from the bash command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. It should be an array of strings like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
));
```

Comment: ... and yes!!!! :) Can't believe it was that simple :(
I thought it was ok to have a "real" array.

Answer (score 0):

Try add curl follow 302 redirect

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Also make sure your http_build_query() function uses "&" as argument separator. On some PHP configurations it may be "& amp;" by default

```
$query = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
```

Comment: I tried with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($curl_parameters, '', '&'));` but still same output (just http header). :(

Answer (score 0):

How about just `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_parameters);`? I don't think you need to call `http_build_query`.

Comment: Nope.. still get just the "302 Found Header"

Comment: I added to the question the output I get with the PHP snippet.

Comment: I should have tested before answering; my bad.

Comment: passing an array results in `multipart/form-data` content instead of the desired `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`